# PHP send multiple event requests to Outlook/vcalendar

Tags: php, outlook

I have a PHP file set up to send an event invitation to Outlook/Vcalendar as follows:

```
    <?php

$message="

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130901T121000Z
DTEND:20130901T131000Z
DTSTAMP:20110525T075116Z
ORGANIZER;CN=From Name:mailto:from email id
UID:12345678
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Sample:emailaddress@testemail.com
DESCRIPTION:Test the first invite
LOCATION: Test Location
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test the first icalendar invitation
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

/*headers*/
$headers = "From: From Name <From Mail>\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST;\n";
$headers .= '        charset="UTF-8"';
$headers .= "\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";

/*mail content*/
$subject = "Meeting Subject";
$subject = html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

/*mail send*/
if(mail("emailaddress@testemail.com", $subject, $message, $headers))

{
    echo "Your request has been sent";
}else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

This works fine. An email is sent to Outlook and when opened, the event is automatically posted to the relevant calendar.

Does anyone know if it is possible to send more than one event that will all be posted when the **single ** email is opened.

I have tried repeating the vcalendar events as follows, but only the first event gets posted.

```
<?php

$message="

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130901T121000Z
DTEND:20130901T131000Z
DTSTAMP:20110525T075116Z
ORGANIZER;CN=From Name:mailto:from email id
UID:12345678
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Sample:emailaddress@testemail.com
DESCRIPTION:Test the first invite
LOCATION: Test Location
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test the first icalendar invitation
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20131001T121000Z
DTEND:20131001T131000Z
DTSTAMP:20110525T075116Z
ORGANIZER;CN=From Name:mailto:from email id
UID:12345678
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Sample:emailaddress@testemail.com
LOCATION: Test the second location
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Test the second icalendar invitation
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

/*headers*/
$headers = "From: From Name <From Mail>\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST;\n";
$headers .= '        charset="UTF-8"';
$headers .= "\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";

/*mail content*/
$subject = "Meeting Subject";
$subject = html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

/*mail send*/
if(mail("emailaddress@testemail.com", $subject, $message, $headers))

{
    echo "Your request has been sent";
}else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

I have also tried to encase each calendar event as a separate declaration (ie $message2 etc) and then to repeat this with the if statement but then of course the event gets sent as a separate email.

Answer (score 2):

After trying multiple approaches, I was able to come up with a working solution.

- You need to send the event as a recurring event.
- 1st inner event should be the default event.
- This should include the RRULE specifying the recurring frequency & count.
- This should contain the same DTSTART, DTEND, DTSTAMP values of the 1st day event.
- All events including the default event should contain the same UID & SEQUENCE.
- Other than the default event, all other events should contain unique RECURRENCE-IDs.

For further details refer to the blog post I have written regarding the solution: http://hasarangi.blogspot.com/2015/02/php-send-multiple-events-to-ms-outlook.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Edited the answer as suggested, any reason why it is still down voted?